# How to open more applications by using single databases per application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

We have a application where you can connect several databases. If you have a connection of one of the databases on your system, you has not to connect on the same database. How do you do that? I mean you can open the system more than once. But all open applications are connected to a different database.

At the moment the system is a single instance system. You can open this once.
I thought by using a List of strings of active database names.

Can somebody advice me?

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Guid guid = new Guid("ABCDEF0-12...."
        ...

        using (SingleInstance instance = new SingleInstance(guid))
        {
            if (instance.IsFirstInstance)
            {
                instance.ArgumentsReceived += instance_ArgumentsReceived;
                instance.ListenForArgumentsFromSuccessiveInstances();

                StartApplication();
            }
            else
            {


public class SingleInstance : IDisposable
{
    ...
    public SingleInstance(Guid identifier)
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        mutex = new Mutex(true, identifier.ToString(), out ownsMutex);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to those databases? You can set the databases in the SINGLE_USER mode if you do.

Comment: On 1 client you can open all databases once. Other users have to use the database too. So SINGLE_USER is not possible.

Comment: Do you simply want to prevent a second instance of your application to run? Are these database connections relevant at all? Your choice of words makes it hard for me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net Connection Pool does a lot of work for you. It is designed, that you benefit from it, if you keep a connection open as short as possible. You open the connection, execute your commands and close it. behind the scenes, the connection will not be "really" closed. It will be kept open a short time. If you open the same connection (same connectionstring) again, you get the alread opened connection from the pool. Therefore a second connection to the same database (at least in one and the same process) will only be opened, if two of them are needed simultaneously. You can limit the size of the pool in the connection string, so setting the limit to 1 should give you one and only one connection all the time, serializing your access (the other thread has to wait). You could run into issues, because even if you open and close the same connection twice in one transactionscope, it will escalate to a distributed transaction. But with using different databases, this will happen in you situation either way. You could prevent it by avoiding transaction(scope)s that span several opens/closes. Or you create a "connectionscope" yourself (I did in in the past to circumvent the escalation problem).

Comment: We have removed the single instance. And when you have rights for more databases, you have to choose which database you use (by login). Else the most users have rights for just 1 database. A totally different solution,